# Multiple lines in ggplot footer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to show a footer on my bar chart, but could not show it as vertical lines.
I am using the layer below, but the text is printed horizontally:

```
labs(caption ="IAT > 95%: OK        90% < IAT <=95%: Warning        IAT <= 90%: 5% Fee")
```

I have tried in other ways, but nothing works well:

1) `labs(caption = paste("IAT > 95%: OK","\n","90% < IAT <=95%: Warning","\n","IAT <= 90%: 5% Fee"))`

2) `labs(caption = cat("IAT > 95%: OK","\n","90% < IAT <=95%: Warning","\n","IAT <= 90%: 5% Fee"))`

Also, I would like to print only the "Ok", "Warning", and "5% Fee" labels in bold.

This is my plot:

```
ggplot(data = indicadorMensal, 
       aes(x = month_Year, y = qtd, label = qtd*100)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = OS),
           position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"),
            vjust = 0.05, size = 3) +
  xlab("Year/Month") +
  ggtitle("IAT Plot",
          subtitle = paste(str_to_title(month(today()-30,
                                              label = TRUE, 
                                              abbr = FALSE)),
                           year(today()))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face="bold",hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"), 
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=11,face="bold"), 
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic", size=7)) +
    **labs(caption ="IAT > 95%: OK        90% < IAT <=95%: Warning IAT <= 90: 5% Fee")** +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Projects") +
  scale_y_continuous("IAT", labels = percent_format())
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Why not just put `"\n"` directly in the text where you want it, instead of using `cat` or `paste`?

Comment: Agreed with camille. `caption = paste("IAT > 95%: OK","\n","90% < IAT <=95%: Warning","\n","IAT <= 90%: 5% Fee")` is a long and inconvenient way to write `caption = "IAT > 95%: OK\n90% < IAT <=95%: Warning\nIAT <= 90%: 5% Fee"`. You would only need paste if you were using variables as parts of the string.

Comment: I tried some ways to solve this and didn't realize it was really simple. Thanks to Camille and Gregor for clarifying.